# Multiple operations within Field Calculator using the same IF statement

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry, distance

I have 2 layers (`Point_Orien_Vert` - red points and `Point_Centroides` - green points), both are Point Geometry.

[image: Attribute tables of both layers]

I need first to check if the distance between one feature in `Point_Orien_Vert` and one feature in `Point_Centroide` is smaller than 180 m.

The code below shows how to calculate this distance and it works inside a IF statement.

```
distance(
 @geometry, 
 closest_point(
  geometry(
   get_feature_by_id(
    'POINT_Centroides',
     array_to_string(
      overlay_nearest(
       'POINT_Centroides', "fid"
      )
     )
    )
   )
  , @geometry
 )
)
```

If the result is true, I need to calculate in `Point_Orien_Vert` layer the difference between the value stored in "Dip_Direct" and the value "Azimute".

**Note that a feature from `Point_Centroide` will be checked more than an once time from points in `Point_Orien_vert` because the distance.**

I do not know how to write this second code using self-referencing geometry to do this operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The closest point of a point geometry, is the point itself. Also, the distance between geometries, is the distance between their closest points.
- "fid" attribute may or may not have the id of the feature as its value. If you delete the feature where "fid" = 1, the second feature "fid" value remains as 2, but its new id is 1.
- Anyways, you don't need its id nor its "fid" value, you need the feature itself. Use the @feature expression in the overlay_nearest function.
- Don't convert the array to string, get its first item. Even if you were getting the id, this is a number not a string.
- Store the feature in a variable for later use in the if clause.

```sql
with_variable( 'closestfeature',
 overlay_nearest( 
  layer:='POINT_Centroides',
  expression:=@feature)[0], --slice index 0 to get the first array item
if(
 distance(@geometry, geometry(@closestfeature)) < 180, --condition
 "Dip_Direct" - attribute(@closestfeature, 'Azimute'), --expression for True
 NULL) --expression for False
)
```

Comment: +1 - A bit shorter: instead of `if` multiply the condition's result (0 or 1) with the difference of `Dip_Direct - Azimute` like this: `(distance (geometry (@closestfeature), $geometry) < 180) * (Dip_Direct - attribute (@closestfeature, 'Azimute'))`

Comment: @Gabriel De Luca thank you very much to help me with this solution and to teach me a bit more about Field Calculator. It works perfectly for my purpose.

Comment: @Babel thank you very much too because you improve the solution and it fits perfectly. Thanks to teach me more about Field Calculator.